# Bootstrap 3.3.5 - Dropdown selected Value width to large text vs small text

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 Dropdown menu. and showing the selected option from dropdown by jQuery.

But I am getting some issue here. I want dropdown-menu and button has to be same width always. That is large text width.

---

> **[Online Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvEGNx)**

---

**HTML**

```
<!-- Dropdown -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="selection">Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet</span><span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /Dropdown -->
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

---

**Please check the images below...**

[image]

---

```
.dropdown-menu{min-width:auto;width:100%;}
```

**If I add Above CSS, Output is...**
[image]

Comment: add css : `.dropdown-menu {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: auto;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have done a little nasty work for you. I changed the `.dropdown-menu` as

```
.dropdown-menu{min-width:auto;width:auto;}
```

And then I wrote a script as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tWidth = $('.dropdown-menu').outerWidth();
   var uWidth = $('.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle').outerWidth();

  if (tWidth>=uWidth){

   $('.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle').css("width", tWidth); 

  }

  else {

     $('.dropdown-menu').css("width", uWidth); 
  }
});
```

What this does is, it checks for the width of the `drop down toggle` and the `.dropdown-menu` and assign the bigger width to the smaller div. So both divs will have the same width.

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjqbQo)

Comment: Thanks **@The Dark Knight**.. Its working in CodePen perfectly.. but not in my page though :(

I am checking the issue. Thanks for your time

Answer (score -1):

CSS

```
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: auto;
   // width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```